# Проблема в QT Creator

Tags: qt5, qtcreator

Всем привет, скачал я Qt, создал проект, передо мной открылся код, вроде все хорошо. Ничего не изменяя я решил запустить его, посмотреть, что тут. Нажал я кнопку запустить, передо мной сразу 10 ошибок "C2433", выглядит вот так:

> C:\Qt6\6.0.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtCore\qglobal.h:379: ошибка: C2433: 'Deprecated': 'inline' not permitted on data declarations

Такая же ошибка и с qOverload, qConstOverload, qNonConstOverload. Еще есть ошибка "C1083"

> C:\Qt6\6.0.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtCore\qcontainerfwd.h:47: ошибка: C1083: Cannot open include file: 'variant': No such file or directory

С чем это связано? Вроде ничего не менял, только создал проект и сразу запустил

Comment: Попробуйте в pro-файл добавить `CONFIG += C++14`

Comment: Не помогло.....

Comment: А вы qmake вызывали после этого? Хотя бы некоторые ошибки должны были измениться.

Comment: Qt6, сырой он ещё